# CSS color "washed or greyed out" on WooCommerce page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

Would anyone be able to help me with this CSS issue? The search bar placeholder text is white but on the WooCommerce page the placeholder text is greyed out. And when I try to change it to any other color it works but the color seems washed out almost like there is a filter placed on it. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Placeholder text greyed out (Woocommerce page)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUg1m.png)

Placeholder text white (other pages)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdTWh.png)

Here's the CSS:

.search-field::placeholder {

color: white!important;

font-size: 20px
}

Comment: Yes, sorry I added it now!

Comment: I believe Woocommerce adds an `opacity` property. Add `opacity: 1` to your CSS to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adjusting the placeholder color specific to the woocommerce element you are trying to modify, for example

```
.woocommerce .search-field::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Edge */
  color: #fff;
}

.woocommerce .search-field:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: #fff;
}

.woocommerce .search-field::placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: .woocommerce .search-field::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Edge */

  color: #fff;

 opacity: 1;

 

}



Worked for me. I really appreciated the help and I apologize for the lack of transparency.